# (JPA/Toplink) Network error IOException: Address already in use: connect

Tags: exception, jpa, networking, toplink-essentials, java-5

I have a JPA project which used to work. This month, I have added some data in my database. When I run the usual job (I used to run on preceeding months), I get this error:

*Exception [TOPLINK-4002] (Oracle TopLink Essentials - 2.0.1 (Build b09d-fcs (12/06/2007))): oracle.toplink.essentials.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Network error IOException: Address already in use: connect
Error Code: 0*

I checked on my LocalPersistenceFacade containing most methods I'm calling, by printing a counter, and I get the exact number of closed and opened connexions there: 457. And then my job crashes. Normally, It should go till 601 and not 457.

On database side, there is no information related to a possible crash. All seems to be correct, but my java code is saying something else.

Did someone have any idea please?

Regards,
Jean

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My understanding is that you are opening/closing a connection for each row and the problem you are facing looks like the one described in [this page](http://doc.boomi.com/confluence/display/DOC/Address+Already+in+Use+Error):

> #### Possible Causes
>
> When running large volume of data
>   through maps that have multiple
>   functions. Windows does not close
>   connections fast enough which causes
>   the Network I/O exception.
>
> #### Recommendations
>
> Modify the following two values in the
>   Windows registry:
>
> This one modifies the range of ports
>   that Windows uses to open connections.
>   By default it only allows up to the
>   port 5000. By modifying this value,
>   Windows will be able to open up more
>   ports before having to recycle back to
>   the beginning. Every connection uses a
>   port, so it starts at 1025 and goes up
>   to this value. When it reaches the max
>   value it goes back to 1025 and tries
>   to open up that port again.
>
> System Key:
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters
>   Name: MaxUserPort Type: REG_DWORD
>   Value: 5000-65534
>
> This will "release" closed ports
>   faster. By default Windows leaves a
>   port in a TIME_WAIT state for 240
>   seconds. This can cause problems if
>   the MaxPort value is set to where a
>   new connection will use an "older"
>   port that has not been removed from
>   TIME_WAIT state yet. By decreasing
>   this value, you allow the connections
>   to be released faster.
>
> System Key:
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters
>   Value Name: TcpTimedWaitDelay Data
>   Type: REG_DWORD Value Data: 30-300

The symptoms and the change - more rows - introduced match perfectly. However, while the suggested "recommendation" may solve the problem, my recommendation would be use connection pooling (use a standalone connection pool like [c3p0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0) or [DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/)). This would IMO solve the problem **and** increase the performances.

Comment: It worked by increasing the number of Max user ports. I think I will set up a connection pool as you suggested. 

Thank you for helping me to figure this out.